# ¿Porque al comparar dos recursos Drawable el valor no es el mismo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buenas, estoy intentando hacer la siguiente comparación.
Yo he verificado que ambos Background sean el mismo, pero aún así la comparación no devuelve un True.

```
if(contenedorMarcas.getBackground() == 
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.contenedor_marcas, null)){
        datos.putBoolean("contenedorActivado", true);
}
```

Verificando el valor de estos por la consola de AndroidStudio me aparecen estos valores, que evidentemente son diferentes:

```
android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable@c749207
android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable@a8a7f34
```

¿Como puedo hacer esta comparación correctamente?

Comment: Hola Victor, ¿Intentas saber su la imagen ya se encuentra cargada en el contenedor?

Comment: Si, si ese recurso drawable ya fue establecido como el Background del layout.

Comment: Prueba obteniendo y comparando el id del resource del drawable y del background.

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con la etiqueta 'android-studio'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador `"=="` compara referencias y en este caso son dos instancias diferentes.

Eso lo puedes comprobar lo que está inmediatamente despues de "@" que es el `hash code` del objeto y como ves en tu caso son diferentes.

Utilizar `.equals()` tampoco es suficiente, en [esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125229/) donde el usuario `@vaughandroid` plantea un algoritmo para comparar igualdad en base a `drawable.getConstantState()` y `Bitmap`

Answer (score 1):

Prueba convertirlos a mapas de bits. Ya que estas comparando los objetos en si y no su contenido.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)Drawable1).getBitmap();
Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)Drawable2).getBitmap();

if(bitmap == bitmap2){
  //Code blcok
}
```